# Creating Deconvolution layer by NetSpec(): SyntaxError

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I am taking baby steps to define the network by `caffe.NetSpec()` function and I am not expert in programming.

I am defining a function to create `Deconvolution` layer for the net by `NetSpec`. The following is the layer definition should be:

```
layer {
name: "deconv1"
type: "Deconvolution"
bottom: "bottom1"
top: "top1"
param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
convolution_param {
num_output: 512
kernel_size: 7
stride: 1
weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant" 
       value: 0    
}
}
}
```

and this is the function definition:

```
def deconv_relu(bottom,nout,ks=3,stride=1,pad=1,std=0.01):
    deconv=L.Deconvolution(bottom,
                           convolution_param=[dict(num_output=nout, kernel_size=ks, stride=stride, pad=pad),
                                                  param=[dict(lr_mult=1, decay_mult=1), dict(lr_mult=2, decay_mult=0)]])


##                           weight_filler=dict(type= 'gaussian', std=std),
##                           bias_filler=dict(type= 'constant',value=0))
    return deconv
```

By adding `weight_filler` and 'bias_filler' , it was showing the following error:

```
 File "./first_try.py", line 78
    n.fc6-deconv=deconv_relu(n.fc7,512,ks=7)
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

and after commenting out those two lines, it is showing this error:

```
File "./first_try.py", line 18
    param=[dict(lr_mult=1, decay_mult=1), dict(lr_mult=2, decay_mult=0)]])
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could someone please help with this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
n.fc6-deconv=deconv_relu(n.fc7,512,ks=7)
```

Gives you an error regardless of your `deconv_relu` implementation, because you are trying to assign value to `n.fc6 - deconv`: python interpret the dash (`-`) in your layer's name as a minus operator. You need to pick a new name for the layer.

As for using `caffeNetSpec()` to define a `"Deconvolution"` layer:

```
deconv=L.Deconvolution(bottom, 
                       convolution_param=dict(num_output=nout,
                                              kernel_size=ks, 
                                              stride=stride, 
                                              pad=pad,
                                              weight_filler=dict(type='gaussian', std=std),
                                              bias_filler=dict(type= 'constant',value=0)),
                       param=[dict(lr_mult=1, decay_mult=1), dict(lr_mult=2, decay_mult=0)]])
```

Note that `convolution_param` gets a `dict` (and not a list of `dict`s),
`weight_filler` and `bias_filler` are part of the `dict` passed to `convolution_params` and
`param` is a list of `dict`s.